# How to get list of only one property form list of object in javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I get following json data  from webAPI

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"wastageName":"BOPP at printing"},
{"id":3,"wastageName":"BOPP Production wastage"},
{"id":18,"wastageName":"LDPEE at leminatign"}]}
```

How can I get only list of wastageName from this data using JavaScript Or JQuery

I think we can apply Loop / each() to solve this problem.

```
$( "data" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using map you can achieve it

```js
const data = {"data":[{"id":1,"wastageName":"BOPP at printing"},
{"id":3,"wastageName":"BOPP Production wastage"},
{"id":18,"wastageName":"LDPEE at leminatign"}]};

const wastageNames = data.data.map(item => item.wastageName);
console.log(wastageNames);
```